# Out of Memory When Performing Gradient Accumulation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement gradient accumulation for a twitter sentiment analysis model using HuggingFace's BERT model. However, when I go to implement gradient accumulation with a batch size of 64, I get the dreaded "OOM" error. Oddly enough, when I go to run my same model with a batch size of 64 and *not using* gradient accumulation, it trains right through. Does anyone know why this is and/or if my code is wrong?

```
batch_size = 32
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)
vocabulary = tokenizer.get_vocab()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam() 
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')

# data preprocessing
tweets_pos = pd.read_csv('C:/1_Tweets.csv', sep=',', names = ['Tweet', 'Sentiment'])
tweets_neg = pd.read_csv('C:/0_Tweets.csv', sep=',', names = ['Tweet',  'Sentiment'])
data = pd.concat([tweets_pos, tweets_neg], axis=0)
data = data.sample(frac=1) 
all_tweets = data['Tweet'].to_list()
all_sentiment = data['Sentiment'].to_list()
training_tweets = all_tweets[0:512]
training_labels = all_sentiment[0:512]

# create dataset
def create_dataset(tweets, labels):
  
  inputs_ids_list = []
  token_type_ids_list = []
  attention_mask_list = []
  label_list = []
  
  for i in range(len(tweets)):
    encoded = tokenizer.encode_plus(tweets[i], max_length = 512, pad_to_max_length=True, return_attention_mask=True, add_special_tokens=True)
    inputs_ids_list.append(encoded['input_ids'])
    token_type_ids_list.append(encoded['token_type_ids'])
    attention_mask_list.append(encoded['attention_mask'])
    label_list.append([labels[i]])

  ids_and_mask = {'input_ids':inputs_ids_list, 'token_type_ids':token_type_ids_list,'attention_mask':attention_mask_list}
  
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((ids_and_mask, label_list))

# create dataset of batch_size = 32
train_dataset = create_dataset(training_tweets, training_labels).batch(batch_size)

# Accumulate Gradients
num_epochs = 1
for i in range(num_epochs):
  print(f'Epoch: {i + 1}')
  total_loss = 0

  # get trainable variables
  train_vars = model.trainable_variables
  accum_gradient = [tf.zeros_like(this_var) for this_var in train_vars]

  for (batch, (tweets, labels)) in enumerate(train_dataset):
      labels = tf.dtypes.cast(labels, tf.float32)
      with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
          prediction = model(tweets, training=True)
          prediction = tf.dtypes.cast(prediction, tf.float32)
          loss_value = loss(y_true=labels, y_pred=prediction)
      total_loss += loss_value

      # get gradients of this tape
      gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, train_vars)
      # Accumulate the gradients
      accum_gradient = [(acum_grad+grad) for acum_grad, grad in zip(accum_gradient, gradients)]


  # average gradients and apply the optimization step
  accum_gradient = [this_grad/batch_size for this_grad in accum_gradient]
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(accum_gradient,train_vars))
      
  epoch_loss = total_loss / batch_size
  print(f'Epoch loss: {epoch_loss}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late for this, but on your question, you are already answering it.

It holds the graph in the memory to correctly calculate the gradient when accumulating gradients. In other words, when accumulating, you have every forward that you have already done in your memory. When not accumulating and using a batch size of 64, TensorFlow flushes the graph after back propping it.

This scenario is why you can train with this batch size of 64 but not accumulate with 64. I don't know why you are trying to accumulate it. However, maybe downsizing your batch size a little if you need it to accumulate.